# String to Date with month all lowercase in java

Tags: java, date

I have a string that contains a date, in the following format:

```
dd-mm-yyyy
```

with the month that is all lowercased. For example:
   25-aug-2019
Now i tried to use SimpleDateFormat to convert my string to a Date, but i have the following exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "25-aug-2019"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.whoislibrary.servers.WhoisCom.parseResponse(WhoisCom.java:37)
    at org.whoislibrary.WhoisAbstract.executeQuery(WhoisAbstract.java:44)
    at org.whoislibrary.WhoisCommand.executeQuery(WhoisCommand.java:69)
    at org.whoislibrary.WhoisMain.main(WhoisMain.java:10)
```

This is the code that i used:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
try {
        Date expDate = df.parse(dateString).trim());
    System.out.println(expDate.toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think the problem is that MM refers to month name that start with a capital letter (Aug, Jul etc). There is an option, or a class like SimpleDateFormat that help me to convert that string into a Date. or it must be done Manually?

Comment: your date is like `25-aug-2019` but should be `25-08-2019` due to your format

Comment: I'd say that he's format is dd-MM-yyyy but should be dd-MMM-yyyy due to his requirements :)

Comment: FYI, whether the month name is uppercase or lowercase depends on the Locale, not the parsing pattern. Some languages and cultures use an initial uppercase letter (US English) and some do not (French).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in your code you have:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Which should be:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Since the month part in your string has 3 letters (MMM) and not 2 (MM)

Answer (score 3):

use `dd-MMM-yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

Your date "25-aug-2019" is in `"dd-MMM-yyyy"` format not `"dd-MM-yyyy"`. So you get parse error. You should use `"dd-MMM-yyyy"` while creating SimpleDateFormat object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    try {
            Date expDate = df.parse("25-aug-2019");
        System.out.println(expDate.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [javaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) java.text.SimpleDateFormat