# change the format to a date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a field of type string to date. Also, I am trying to change the date format. I have not been successful, because everything is showing me null.

the field:

```
+-------------------------+
|financial_statements_date|
+-------------------------+
|                06-sep-12|
|                26-jul-12|
|                02-sep-11|
|                02-dic-09|
|                24-jun-15|
|                19-oct-15|
|                02-sep-13|
|                17-feb-09|
|                24-ago-10|
|                10-ago-16|
|                12-jul-16|
|                27-jul-20|
|                31-dic-02|
|                02-abr-08|
|                17-sep-19|
+-------------------------+
```

result:

```
+--------------------+
|gf_company_size_date|
+--------------------+
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
+--------------------+
```

my code :

```
df.select(
to_date(col("financial_statements_date"),"YYYY-MM-DD").as("gf_company_size_date")
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast column containing multiple string date formats to DateTime in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594750/cast-column-containing-multiple-string-date-formats-to-datetime-in-spark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're date format is incorrect and should have 3 `M` in there. Also, I think the format is day, month, year (instead of year, month, day (looking at the sample data)). So, I think the format should be:

```
dd-MMM-yy
```

Re-running with the new format and first 3 records, they are now parsed as:

```
+-------------------------+
|financial_statements_date|
+-------------------------+
|                06-sep-12|
|                26-jul-12|
|                02-sep-11|
+-------------------------+

+--------------------+
|gf_company_size_date|
+--------------------+
|          2012-09-06|
|          2012-07-26|
|          2011-09-02|
+--------------------+
```

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907693/864369

Comment: it's working partially, with the following dates it keeps returning null: 
02-dic-09, 24-ago-10, 10-ago-16, 31-dic-02, 02-abr-08. Any idea why?

Comment: I think that is for language, my data is in Spanish, for example, ago=agosto, dic=diciembre